# script.js doesnt look like connecting to html file

Tags: javascript

Im just learninng javascript, and wanted to play around, but looks like the script doesnt connect to html page. I dont understand why.

thats in html:

```
<body>
  <main>
<div class="tank">
  <img id="tank2" src="tank.gif" alt="Tank Girl" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="hiGirl()>

   </div>
   </main>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
```

And thats in script.js:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
 window.alert('Hi, Im tank Girl')
})

document.getElementById('tank2').onclick = function hiGirl () {
var userName = window.prompt('What is your name?', 'Enter your name here.')
if (userName) {
window.alert(`Szia Mia ${userName} !`)
} else { window.alert('Hello Stranger!') }
}
```

Comment: in the begining I also tryed only write

Comment: If you're adding a listener to the `img` in JS, which is the right way to do things, don't set `onclick="..."` in the HTML (which is an ancient way to write js event handlers). However, don't ever use `alert()`, it's not 1998 anymore: use `console.log(...)` and look at your dev tools console. You should have that open already anyway, because it will tell you when things couldn't load, or if you wrote some JS with errors in it, etc. Also on the modern-HTML note: start your document with `<!doctype html>` so that it's known HTML5, and remove `type=...` from `<script>`: it's JS by default.

Comment: Are your js and html files in the same folder? Do you see any js or network errors in the developer console?

Comment: Sure, I have doctype, and all, it just wasnt relevant for the question.

Comment: .I changed alerts to console.log, but it doesnt give the same effect, or you mean only for debugging? Devtools was my first try, but couldnt find js in consol. I still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an syntax error on `onclick` in `img` tag, correct it:

```html
<img id="tank2" src="tank.gif" alt="Tank Girl" style="cursor:pointer"  onclick="hiGirl()">
```

Or just basically remove it as below because you added a `onclick` handler in `script.js`, so no need to use it on `img` tag:

```html
<img id="tank2" src="tank.gif" alt="Tank Girl" style="cursor:pointer">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was the extra onclick. Now its working.

Comment: You are welcome, please help me mark it as answer because it's voted down hic